# "missing filename" compilation Error

Tags: arduino-ide, compile

I've recently got back to my Uno. I tried compiling my program and got the following error:

```
Arduino: 1.6.6 (Windows 8.1), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

avr-g++: error: missing filename after '-o'

exit status 1
Error compiling.
```

This happens on any of the programs I've tried to compile/upload.
I've searched around on Google but I have gotten no definite answers and how to fix this or what has caused this? Does anyone have an idea on what I could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem. You should download Arduino IDE 1.6.8

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software